# Accessing JSON returns undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

Can someone point me what am I doing wrong? Below is my json returned from Amazon webservices for order items and I am using the below code in react,node to print the quantityOrdered and I am getting undefined

```
    { OrderItems:
   { OrderItem:
      { QuantityOrdered: '1',
        Title: 'X',
        ShippingTax: [Object],
        PromotionDiscount: [Object],
        ConditionId: 'New',
        IsGift: 'false',
        ASIN: 'X',
        SellerSKU: 'X',
        OrderItemId: 'X',
        ShippingDiscountTax: [Object],
        ProductInfo: [Object],
        GiftWrapTax: [Object],
        QuantityShipped: '0',
        ShippingPrice: [Object],
        GiftWrapPrice: [Object],
        ConditionSubtypeId: 'New',
        ItemPrice: [Object],
        ItemTax: [Object],
        ShippingDiscount: [Object],
        PromotionDiscountTax: [Object] } },
  AmazonOrderId: 'X,
  ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'X' },
  Headers:
   { 'x-mws-quota-max': 'unknown',
     'x-mws-quota-remaining': 'unknown',
     'x-mws-quota-resetson': 'unknown',
     'x-mws-timestamp': 'X',
     'content-type': 'text/xml',
     'content-charset': 'unknown',
     'content-length': '2172',
     'content-md5': 'unknown',
     date: 'Sun, 14 Oct 2018 17:00:05 GMT' },
  StatusCode: 200 }
```

Below is my code

```
 var Obj = response;
  console.log(Obj);
if (typeof Obj !== 'undefined') {
   var objectValue = Obj;                                        
   console.log(objectValue.OrderItem.QuantityOrdered);
 }
```

Error:

```
    console.log(objectValue.OrderItem.QuantityOrdered);
                                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'QuantityOrdered' of undefined
```

Comment: should be `OrderItem` instead of `OrderItems`

Comment: response.OrderItem.QuantityOrdered ?

Comment: Updated my json reposone and the code ,still the same issue

Comment: got it to work with  response.OrderItems.OrderItem.QuantityOrdered. Thanks all for pointers

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your JSON is valid, there are a couple of mistakes in the response you've provided. Once fixed you will be able to access the response like so:

```js
(function() {
  var __awsJSON = {
    OrderItems: {
      OrderItem: {
        QuantityOrdered: '1',
        Title: 'X',
        IsGift: 'false',
      }
    },
    AmazonOrderId: 'X',
    Headers: {
      date: 'Sun, 14 Oct 2018 17:00:05 GMT'
    },
    StatusCode: 200,
  };
  
  document.getElementById('quantity-ordered').textContent = __awsJSON.OrderItems.OrderItem.QuantityOrdered;
  document.getElementById('amazon-id').textContent = __awsJSON.AmazonOrderId;
  document.getElementById('date').textContent = __awsJSON.Headers.date;
  document.getElementById('status-code').textContent = __awsJSON.StatusCode;

})();
```

```html
<pre>__awsJSON.OrderItems.OrderItem.QuantityOrdered</pre>
<div>Quantity ordered: <span id="quantity-ordered"></span></div>

<pre>__awsJSON.AmazonOrderId</pre>
<div>Amazon ID: <span id="amazon-id"></span></div>

<pre>__awsJSON.Headers.date</pre>
<div>Headers ~ Date: <span id="date"></span></div>

<pre>__awsJSON.StatusCode</pre>
<div>Status Code: <span id="status-code"></span></div>
```